# WooCommerce: How to retain checkout info when client leaves then comes back?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, cart

Is there a simple way or a plugin to retain checkout information entered by the client after he/she leaves and comes back?

[This plugin](https://ur.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-checkout-manager/) retains "fields information for customers when they navigate back and forth" however it has quite a lot of recent bad reviews so I don't think I'll use that for production. Any alternative suggestion?

Answer (score 11):

**---- Update ----**

*The code below is working, but only if data is submitted!*

The only possible ways are javascript/jQuery form event detection on checkout fields and worpress Ajax:

- Using ajax connected to some session transients function *(as in code below)*.
- Using *(javascript)* web Storage: [`localStorage`, `sessionStorage`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)…

---

I have found some real interesting code in [**this thread**](http://twentyzerotwo.co.uk/wordpress/how-to-make-woocommerce-checkout-persistent) that is using sessions transients to store checkout data.

```
// this function sets the checkout form data as session transients whenever the checkout page validates
function set_persitent_checkout ( $a ) {
    $arr = array();
    foreach ( $a as $key => $value )
        if ( ! empty($value) )
            $arr[$key] = $value;

    WC()->session->set( 'form_data', $arr );
    return $a;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'set_persitent_checkout' );


// this function hooks into woocommerce_checkout_get_value to substitute standard values with session values if present
function get_persistent_checkout ( $value, $index ) {
    $data = WC()->session->get('form_data');
    if ( ! $data || empty($data[$index]) )
        return $value;
    return is_bool($data[$index]) ? (int) $data[$index] : $data[$index];
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_get_value', 'get_persistent_checkout', 10, 2 );


// This is a fix for the ship_to_different_address field which gets it value differently if there is no POST data on the checkout
function get_persitent_ship_to_different ( $value ) {
    $data = WC()->session->get('form_data');
    if ( ! $data || empty($data['ship_to_different_address']) )
        return $value;

    return is_bool($data['ship_to_different_address']) ? (int) $data['ship_to_different_address'] : $data['ship_to_different_address'];
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked', 'get_persitent_ship_to_different' );
```

*Add this code to the `functions.php` file located in your active child theme or theme.*

Explanations from the author:

**1. Save the form data:**

The first function `set_persitent_checkout` hooks into `woocommerce_after_checkout_validation`.

Whenever that hook is fired, any current form data is saved as a WordPress transient via the `WC_Session_Handler` class (which was recently updated in version 2.5 to be a lot more efficient).

**2. Check the saved data on reload:**

Next we hook `woocommerce_checkout_get_value with get_persitent_checkout`. As the name suggests, here we check the session transients and return any matches for the current field if found.

**3. Make `ship_to_different_address` work:**

The only difficult was the `ship_to_different_address` field, which gets its value through a different method.

To get around this the final function was added. This works exactly the same as the previous function, but hooks into `woocommerce_ship_to_different_address_checked`.

There you have it. It would be nice if the data was saved after every field update on checkout, but the `woocommerce_after_checkout_validation` hook fires enough to capture the data at all the important points.

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec. Doesn't seem to have any effect though: what I input in the fields is gone once I visit another page of the site and go back to checkout page.

Comment: OMG, thanks!  This appears to be **the only valid solution** that has been documented on the net thus far.  WooCommerce did not store the checkout form values for anonymous users after submit, so the checkout form user input was lost in my multi-step checkout implementation when the checkout page was refreshed or reloaded. I do consider this a bug in WooCommerce Core and will file a corresponding issue as soon as time permits (this customer user input form values madness unexpectedly sucked up entire days recently). Especially thanks for the shipping address checkbox tidbit! <3

Answer (score 0):

Functions.php snipped posted by LoicTheAztec didn't work for me.

I found this plugin which remembers everything I type or select in Woocommerce checkout, including shipping fields and my custom additions to the template:

[Save Abandoned Carts – WooCommerce Live Checkout Field Capture](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-save-abandoned-carts/#description)

Account passwords, if creating during checkout, are naturally not remembered.